# How to remove one of item in aray object and update state after that?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state "Bill" and I want to delete one of item in "Product" with "ProductID". So how can I do it?

```
Bill = {
  "Bill_ID" : "a00231",
  "Products" : [
    {
      "ProductID" : "P0203",
      "ProductName" : "ABCD"
    },
    {
      "ProductID" : "P023243",
      "ProductName" : "ZYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I update the state after delete product item?

Comment: Please post the code, asking for a solution without initial struggle doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the`pop()` method. You can pop the last element from your products array and look at the popped element. Something like:

```
var poppedElement = Bill.Products.pop();
console.log(Bill)              //Bill withoug last Products element
console.log(poppedElement)     //just the last element of Products
```

Not sure if this will work completely off the top of my head, but hopefully will give you a starting place at least :)

Check out this link for more info: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: thats assuming he wants to delete the last item

Comment: Ah, forgot about the "ProductId", got carried away, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `bill.products` array, like following (note it must be `!=` not `==`)

```
bill.products.filter(x => x != yourDesiredToBeDeletedId)
```

> Treat this.state as if it were immutable

Since your `state` contains an array within an object, I suggest to use [lodash's cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep).

```
let newBill = _.cloneDeep(this.bill);
newBill.products = newBill.products.filter(x => x != yourDesiredToBeDeletedId);
this.setState(bill: newBill);
```